# PHP - Adding prefix to String array during an explode

Tags: php, explode, arrays

Ok, am trying to figure out the best way to do this.  I have code as follows:

```
$context['dp_module_headers'] = array();
```

Than later on down within the function within a while loop I iterate through all foldernames and apply the path to this array.  But the paths are relative to the folder names, so I need to include the folder names within the values of the exploded array.

```
$context['dp_module_headers'] += explode('+', $row[$type . '_header_files']);
```

This can return an array like so:

```
$context['dp_module_headers'][0] = 'source/script.js';
$context['dp_module_headers'][1] = 'source/script.css';
$context['dp_module_headers'][2] = 'source/script.js';
$context['dp_module_headers'][3] = 'mydir/style.css';
```

I need to pre-pend the folder name before all values within the array.  I only have access to the folder name that it is in when within the function that does the explode.  So within the other function of a different file, I don't have access to the folder name that these paths link to.

So, when doing the explode, I need to pre-pend the folders name before each path within the value of each array.

So, basically, this array needs to return the following instead:

```
$context['dp_module_headers'][0] = 'sitenews/source/script.js';
$context['dp_module_headers'][1] = 'sitenews/source/script.css';
$context['dp_module_headers'][2] = 'userpanel/source/script.js';
$context['dp_module_headers'][3] = 'userpanel/mydir/style.css';
```

I have a variable called `$folder` that gets changed per `explode`, but how can I add the `$folder` name string variable to the beginning of each value while exploding it?  Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With PHP 5.3+, you can use something like this:

```
$context['dp_module_headers'] += array_map(
    function ($path) use ($folder) { return $folder . $path; },
    explode('+', $row[$type . '_header_files'])
);
```

That's a little more awkward to with with 5.2-, there you should save your exploded paths in a variable, loop over that array, prepend the `$folder` value to each value, *then* add the result to your `$context` array.

Comment: Thanks a million.  I actually thought about this some and created another array bound.  `$context['dp_module_headers'][$folder] = explode('+', $row[$type . '_header_files']);` than within the other file, I just perform 2 foreach loops.  The first one gives me the folders name, the second loop gives me the path within the values.  This works like a charm, especially since the $folder variable will never have spaces and only has 1 folder name.